# Return URL on verification

Tags: meteor

What sets the return URL for the verification email.  Not the link that gets generated and inserted in the email, but when you click the link, it ends up going to a page on your site after its verified.  How can I set what page it goes to?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the URL by specifying [Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_emailtemplates). Here's an example:

```js
Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = 'MyApp';

Accounts.emailTemplates.from = 'me@example.com';

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.subject = function() {
  return 'Verify your email address on MyApp';
};

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text = function(user, url) {
  var token = url.split('/').pop();
  var verifyEmailUrl = Meteor.absoluteUrl("verify-email/" + token);
  return verifyEmailEmailBody(verifyEmailUrl);
};
```

The callback takes a `url` parameter which is the default URL generated by meteor. You can extract the verification token and then use it to build a custom URL. The function needs to return a body string, which you'll generate by implementing `verifyEmailEmailBody`.

On the client, you'll need to set up the corresponding route. When the route is run, you can call `Accounts.verifyEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the verification url used in the email and then handle that route yourself. Here I'll use `/verify` and redirect to `/wherever` if successful.

**client**

```js
var match = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/verify\/(.*)$/);
var token;

if (match) {
  token = match[1];
}

Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (token) {
    Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function (error) {
      if (!error) {
        window.location.pathname = '/wherever';
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**server**

```js
Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function (token) {
  return Meteor.absoluteUrl('verify/' + token);
};
```